# Cannot generate classes because top-leel elements with complex type were found

Tags: xml, xsd

I have all the included XSD's that this XSD is looking for. I run the XSD.exe (xsd AuctionAccountType.xsd /c) and I get the error message that you see in the title of this thread... I'vr searched for the answer and found a few examples, tried them and it dosen't work. Any ideas?

If you take out the included files you should be able to create (try create) the CS file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:cs="http://www.manheim.com/2009/01/CustSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.manheim.com/2009/01/CustSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:include schemaLocation="LocationAccountType.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="PostalAddressType.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="ElectronicAddressType.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="TelecomNumberType.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="ManheimDemoTypes.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="GlobalDemoTypes.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="AccountAssociationType.xsd"/>
<xs:complexType name="AuctionAccountType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SystemKeys" type="cs:SystemKeysType"/>
        <xs:element name="action" type="cs:actionCode" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="sourceDeleteIndicator" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element name="auctionAcctNum" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="description" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="customerAccountDesignation" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="remarketingIndicator" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="publicSaleOnlyIndicator" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
                        <xs:attribute name="setNULL" type="xs:boolean"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="buySellCode" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="status" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="distributionCode" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="accountDbaName" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="optionCode" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="FLNDRCode" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="groupCode" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="checkIndicator" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
                        <xs:attribute name="setNULL" type="xs:boolean"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="legacyNULCode" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="legacyCommGroupCode" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="changed" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="previousValue" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="PostalAddress" type="cs:PostalAddressType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="ElectronicAddress" type="cs:ElectronicAddressType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="TelecomNumber" type="cs:TelecomNumberType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="LocationAccount" type="cs:LocationAccountType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="AccountAssociation" type="cs:AccountAssociationType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a top level element 'root element' in your schema, without that all you have are the complex type definitions. You can't create XML directly from a complex type, you need to define something that is baed on the complexType definition, in your exmaple you would have to have an element definition that is of type 'AuctionAccountType'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2015 Developer Bundle Edition 12.1.2.5004 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="AuctionAccount"
                type="AuctionAccountType" />
    <xs:complexType name="AuctionAccountType">
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
```

[image]